# How to make DenseNet followed by Inception

Tags: keras, deep-learning

I want to create a model with DenseNet201 followed by InceptionV3, based on the paper https://www.researchgate.net/publication/339653204_Detection_of_rice_plant_diseases_based_on_deep_transfer_learning on page 3251.

But I couldn't find a way to do this. I have the input of shape `[448, 448, 3]` and the base models:

```
model1 = DenseNet201(include_top=False, weights="imagenet", input_shape=[448,448,3])
model2 = InceptionResNetV2(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)
```

I tried combining them this way

```
ip = model1(inputs)
ip = model2(ip)
```

according to the architecture in the paper, but this resulted in dimension incompatibility.

Comment: At page 3251 in table 2 they present the intermediate sized and in the previous page they say that they added an adaptation layer in-between the two networks, try do to this.

Comment: Thanks @Louis Lac . But the previous page only mentioned the freezing of weights and removal of a densely connected layer. What I need is an intermediate layer handling the output of DenseNet and giving it to Inception.

Comment: From the paper, it seems like they don't use the full Inception net but just a single Inception module, which you could adapt [from the source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/85c8b2a817f95a3e979ecd1ed95bff1dc1335cff/tensorflow/python/keras/applications/inception_resnet_v2.py#L153) and put after the DenseNet layers. Then you can use max pooling, etc.

Comment: Thanks, @AaronKeesing. I didn't notice that. One more thing that troubled me was how the transition Layer 3 outputted (28, 28, 128) while this layer of DenseNet121 actually gives (7, 7, 1902). The 1902 number is the number of units just before GlobalAvaragePooling2D(). This sounded suspicious to me.

Comment: They say they use DenseNet-201, but it seems like only the first 3 dense/transition blocks. I just did a quick test and it seems that the layer `pool3_conv` has output shape `(28, 28, 256)` but that's at the end of transition block 2 before average pooling. So it's unclear exactly what they did. You're probably going to have to guess a lot of what they did since the paper is not particularly clear.

Comment: If you want to implement, I would recommend ignoring their table of output shapes and just stacking an Inception module and pooling at the end of DenseNet and try work with that.

Comment: Thank @AaronKeesing a lot for your suggestion. Indeed, the paper is quite unclear.